# Loading data into existing BQ table using google java client

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Tried to load a BQ table from CSV file in the bucket but ran into below error for field issueid which is of REQUIRED and rest of the fields are NULLABLE.

> com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Provided Schema does not
> match Table hd-pricing-dev:merch_meter.jira_issues_csv_load. Field
> issueid has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE

code is similar to the one in this link https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/main/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/LoadCsvFromGcs.java

except Schema definition I have is different

```
Schema schema = Schema.of(
                Field.of("teamid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("jiraboardid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("issueid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),// ??? do i need to pass here something else
                Field.of("issuetype", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("sprintid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("status", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("createddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
                Field.of("completeddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
                Field.of("sprintstartdate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
                Field.of("sprintenddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
                Field.of("lastupdateduser", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("lastupdateddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
                Field.of("issuepoints", StandardSQLTypeName.INT64),
                Field.of("creatoremailaddress", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("creatordisplayname", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("creatoraccountid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("creatorisactive", StandardSQLTypeName.BOOL),
                Field.of("components", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("labels", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("issueName", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("parentissueid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("parentissuetype", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("isDeleted", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
                Field.of("runDate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP)
        );
```

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: does this table exist on bigquery already ? Can you check programmatically what does schema print for issueid in case you load schema directly ? 
`BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
      Table table = bigquery.getTable(datasetName, tableId);
      Schema schema = table.getDefinition().getSchema();
      FieldList fields = schema.getFields();`

Comment: Yeah I tried your suggestion and it prints this for issueId

Table table = bigQuery.getTable(XCELERATE_BQ_DATASET, XCELERATE_JIRA_ISSUES_TABLE);
  Schema schema = table.getDefinition().getSchema();
  FieldList fields = schema.getFields();

  for (int i =0; i< fields.size();i++) {
   Field field = fields.get(i);
   System.out.println(field.getName()+", mode ="+field.getMode());
  }
printed the below line

issueid, mode =REQUIRED

Comment: So what mode does it print for issueId ?

Comment: REQUIRED 
Do I have to do anything for this column in the above code?

Comment: Can you add full stack trace of error that you are seeing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to declare the `issueid` field as `REQUIRED` to solve your issue, you can do that with a `Builder` proposed on the `Field` class :

```java
Schema schema = Schema.of(
    Field.of("teamid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("jiraboardid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),

    // Builder here with REQUIRED Mode.
    Field.newBuilder("issueid", LegacySQLTypeName.STRING)
            .setMode(Field.Mode.REQUIRED)
            .build(),
    // Field.of("issueid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),// ??? do i need to pass here something else
    Field.of("issuetype", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("sprintid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("status", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("createddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
    Field.of("completeddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
    Field.of("sprintstartdate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
    Field.of("sprintenddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
    Field.of("lastupdateduser", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("lastupdateddate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP),
    Field.of("issuepoints", StandardSQLTypeName.INT64),
    Field.of("creatoremailaddress", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("creatordisplayname", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("creatoraccountid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("creatorisactive", StandardSQLTypeName.BOOL),
    Field.of("components", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("labels", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("issueName", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("parentissueid", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("parentissuetype", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("isDeleted", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING),
    Field.of("runDate", StandardSQLTypeName.TIMESTAMP)
);
```